# Transform values in a line by first field

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing

I was wondering if there is an easy way to do the following without writing a script.

Transform

```
1234,"a;b;d"
2345,"e;f;g;h"
```

to

```
1234,a
1234,b
1234,d
2345,e
2345,f
2345,g
2345,h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[";]' -vOFS='' '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)print $1,$i}' file
1234,a
1234,b
1234,d
2345,e
2345,f
2345,g
2345,h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE  '/(.*?)"(.*)"/;  say "$1$_" for split /;/,$2'
```